# MS Access 2007 sql functions?

Tags: sql, ms-access, function

Does MS Access 2007 support creation of user defined sql functions?
if so, where is the option for it in the menu?

Comment: Do you mean: a) user defined functions that can be *used* in Access SQL; b) user defined functions that can be *defined* using Access SQL; c) something else?

Comment: Access Data Projects support SQL Server user-defined functions. Yes.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean can you use User Defined Functions (UDF) in SQL in Access, yes you can. For example, if you wanted the median value, you might write SQL in the query design window like so:

```
SELECT s.Month, 
       Sum(([SentTo])) AS [Sum Sent], 
       fMedian("Statistics","Month",[Month],"SentTo") AS [Median Sent]
FROM Statistics s
GROUP BY s.Month
```

Where fMedian refers to code in a module:

```
Function fMedian(SQLOrTable, GroupFieldName, GroupFieldValue, MedianFieldName)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQLOrTable, dbOpenDynaset)

    If IsDate(GroupFieldValue) Then
        GroupFieldValue = "#" & GroupFieldValue & "#"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(GroupFieldValue) Then
        GroupFieldValue = "'" & Replace(GroupFieldValue, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If

    rs1.Filter = GroupFieldName & "=" & GroupFieldValue
    rs1.Sort = MedianFieldName

    Set rs = rs1.OpenRecordset()
    rs.Move (rs.RecordCount / 2)

    If rs.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
        varMedian1 = rs.Fields(MedianFieldName)
        rs.MoveNext
        fMedian = (varMedian1 + rs.Fields(MedianFieldName)) / 2
    Else
        fMedian = rs.Fields(MedianFieldName)
    End If

End Function
```

From: [http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Aggregate_Median_(UDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170325092342/http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Aggregate_Median_(UDF))

Comment: interesting... do you have any sample data for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom functions using VBA Module Functions.

Have a look at [Build Custom Functions for Your Access Applications](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut04.htm)

Comment: You can create *VBA functions*, that you can use in you *MS Access Queries*.

Comment: @Haim Bender: what's a "real SQL function"?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "what's a 'real SQL function'" -- presumably one that can be defined using Standard SQL/PSM CREATE FUNCTION (e.g. http://www.postgres.cz/index.php/SQL/PSM_Manual) or similar proprietary SQL syntax (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

queries can take parameters which makes them similar to stored procedures. Functions can be achieved through VBA.