# Block if without end if

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I am very new to VBA. I tried to calculate median for a vector. The following code keeps getting warning regarding "Block if without End if". I tried to change the place of "End IF", but it resulted in another warning "Block end if without if". Your input would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub CalculateMedian()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim onet As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Ocode As String
    Dim ag As DAO.Recordset
    Dim agMedian As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'select one variable in current database
    Set onet = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ONetCode FROM Single WHERE LEN(ONetCode)>8")

    Do While Not onet.EOF

        'assigning value to a variable does not need a "SET"
        Ocode = onet.Fields("ONetCode")
        'any data meet the criterion--&Ocode& can vary
        Set ag = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT AG FROM Single WHERE ONetCode='" & Ocode & "' ORDER BY AG")

        'using .recordcount needs to use .movelast first
        ag.MoveLast
        ag.MoveFirst
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1 Then
            agMedian = ((ag.RecordCount + 1) / 2)
            thecount = 0
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                thecount = thecount + 1
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                    'inset the result into a new table, and need to create a new table in advance
                    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO PCImedian(onetcode, agMedian) VALUES('" & Ocode & "'," & ag("AG") & ");")
                    Exit Do
        End If

       If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
            agMedian = ag.RecordCount / 2
            thecount = 0
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                thecount = thecount + 1
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                    m1 = ag("AG")
                ElseIf thecount = agMedian + 1 Then
                    m2 = ag("AG")
                    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO PCImedian(onetcode, agMedian) VALUES('" & Ocode & "'," & ((m1 + m2) / 2) & ");")
                    Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896161/ms-access-2007-sql-functions/1896461?noredirect=1#comment26805083_1896461 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213892/whats-the-difference-between-docmd-setwarnings-and-currentdb-execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was missing more than one `End If`.  And there were 2 missing `Loop` statements as well.

When the code is complex enough that sorting out the block end statements becomes challenging, make a copy of the procedure and throw away basically everything other than the block control statements.  That method leaves this from your current code.

```vb
    Do While Not onet.EOF
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1 Then
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                If thecount = agMedian Then
        End If
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                ElseIf thecount = agMedian + 1 Then
        End If
    Loop
```

And here is my best guess for what you need instead.  I appended comments to several of those statements because it helps me match them up properly.

```vb
    Do While Not onet.EOF
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1 Then
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                End If ' thecount
            Loop ' Not ag.EOF
        End If ' ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                ElseIf thecount = agMedian + 1 Then
                End If ' thecount
            Loop ' Not ag.EOF
        End If ' ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0
    Loop ' Not onet.EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

it appears you're missing an end if after the exit do in the first block of code.  There should be 2 there, one to close out the last if statement, and one to close out the first block.

```
Sub CalculateMedian()

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim onet As DAO.Recordset

    Dim Ocode As String
    Dim ag As DAO.Recordset
    Dim agMedian As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'select one variable in current database
    Set onet = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ONetCode FROM Single WHERE LEN(ONetCode)>8")

    Do While Not onet.EOF

        'assigning value to a variable does not need a "SET"
        Ocode = onet.Fields("ONetCode")
        'any data meet the criterion--&Ocode& can vary
        Set ag = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT AG FROM Single WHERE ONetCode='" & Ocode & "' ORDER BY AG")

        'using .recordcount needs to use .movelast first
        ag.MoveLast
        ag.MoveFirst
        If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1 Then
            agMedian = ((ag.RecordCount + 1) / 2)
            thecount = 0
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                thecount = thecount + 1
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                    'inset the result into a new table, and need to create a new table in advance
                    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO PCImedian(onetcode, agMedian) VALUES('" & Ocode & "'," & ag("AG") & ");")


                   End If 'ends the If thecount = agMedian if statement -- will continue to iterate until EOF

                    Exit Do 'EOF hit.


        End If 'ends the If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 1 block

       If ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0 Then
            agMedian = ag.RecordCount / 2
            thecount = 0
            Do While Not ag.EOF
                thecount = thecount + 1
                If thecount = agMedian Then
                    m1 = ag("AG")
                ElseIf thecount = agMedian + 1 Then
                    m2 = ag("AG")
                    DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO PCImedian(onetcode, agMedian) VALUES('" & Ocode & "'," & ((m1 + m2) / 2) & ");")
                    Exit Do
        End If 'thecount = agMedian if statement
        End If 'end ag.RecordCount Mod 2 = 0

    Loop

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to add end if between "exit do" and "end if", and did in each block. But it gave a warning as "End if without if".

Comment: updated answer to make it a little more visible as to what you were missing.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it based on your advice, but it gave an error message "End if without block if".

Comment: sorry I didn't get back to this now, and it looks like there's already an answer, but I fixed up the second block of code, as you were missing an end if there as well.